# Why is Firebase Storage "rules_version = '2'" getting overriden?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I've appended the following line to my storage rules following the docs:
`rules_version = '2';`
Furthermore, my rules are now:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover, I am able to list out the files of a folder using `listAll` which is an exclusively version 2 feature.

However, each day I come back to my dashboard to find my rules updated to the previous version, being:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

How and why does this happen? More importantly, how may I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from Jonathan from Firebase who was kind enough to remind me of the fact that I am deploying almost on a daily basis I figured out what was going wrong. It turned out that as part of my continuous deployment I was also deploying Firebase storage rules, hence I was indirectly the one overriding my own rules.

Now the obvious and easy solution is to just update the storage.rules file locally.

Comment: Additionally, the same applies for `firestore.rules`.

Answer (score 1):

There are [only three ways your rules can change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy):

1. Using the Firebase console
2. Using the Firebase CLI to deploy rules from a local file
3. Use the Firebase Admin SDK.

If your rules are changing and you are absolutely certain that it's not coming from one of these two methods, [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.